# sql - select case statement to add time cut-off

Tags: mysql, sql, time, analysis

I have this table that contains created order time, as well as received, inprocess, assigned, and delivered time. As well as a view that calculates their average times. I'm trying to add a clause that has orders submitted after 8:00PM (closing time) be taken in as 8:00AM(business opens)the next day to maintain the correct average times. Here is the orders
[![table: ][1]][1] And this is the view I'm using to calculate the average time

```
SELECT 
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`received_time`,
            `sales`.`inprocess_time`)) AS `avg_prepare`,
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`inprocess_time`,
            `sales`.`assigned_time`)) AS `avg_assign`,
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`assigned_time`,
            `sales`.`delivered_time`)) AS `avg_delivery`,
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`received_time`,
            `sales`.`delivered_time`)) AS `avg_total`
    FROM
        `customer_orders` `sales`
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can make use of case statement to transform the value of order submitted  after 8PM , you can add +12 hours. Please add the actual data rather than image.

Comment: By data you mean dbfiddle?

Comment: Thats the best or you can simply paste the data in question but not the image.

Comment: Do you want me to literally paste the data in the post, or link to the excel?

Comment: Anything will work as long as we have access to the data to test it.

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220154/discussion-between-mohd-atif-and-neykof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`received_time`,
            `sales`.`inprocess_time`)) AS `avg_prepare`,
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`inprocess_time`,
            `sales`.`assigned_time`)) AS `avg_assign`,
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`assigned_time`,
            `sales`.`delivered_time`)) AS `avg_delivery`,
        AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
            `sales`.`received_time`,
            `sales`.`delivered_time`)) AS `avg_total`
    FROM
        (SELECT 
              CASE WHEN TIME(received_time) > '20:00:00' THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(received_time), INTERVAL 32 HOUR) 
                   WHEN TIME(received_time) <= '07:59:59' THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(received_time), INTERVAL 8 HOUR) 
                   ELSE received_time 
              END as received_time
           ,inprocess_time
           ,assigned_time
           ,delivered_time
        FROM `customer_orders`
        WHERE created_on between '2020-08-01' AND '2020-09-01'
        ) AS `sales`
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel! Although when I try to add a where clause to have it run only on orders from August it gives me an error?

Comment: I have updated my query. My guess you is that you were applying the filter on the parent query instead of the subquery. You can still apply the filter in the parent query but you can only use the columns from the subquery. So you can either do what I did, or just ad the created_on column in the select list of the subquery and then you can use it to filter the parent query.

Comment: isn't this query missing a part in CASE for the orders received between 00:00 and 07:59?

Comment: very good catch Ivo P. I have adjusted my query to cover those cases as well.

Comment: Thank you both. @GabrielDurac,  since we can take orders at any time wouldn't the interval be 12 hours?

Comment: `WHEN TIME(received_time) > '20:00:00' THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(received_time), INTERVAL 32 HOUR) ` this means for orders after 8 PM take the date without time and add 32 hous (a day and 8h ) - meaning 8 AM the next day. `WHEN TIME(received_time) <= '07:59:59' THEN DATE_ADD(DATE(received_time), INTERVAL 8 HOUR) ` For orders that came before 8 AM, take the date without time and add 8 hours - meaning 8 AM today. So I do not shift the time by a set amount of hours, I set them as per your request to be at 8 AM the following day.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @GabrielDurac, again I really appreciate your help with all this.